# Adjusting the relative space of facets (without regard to coordinate space)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a primary graph and some secondary information that I want to facet in another graph below it.  Facetting works great except I do not know how to control the relative space used by one facet versus another.   Am aware of space='free' but this is only useful if the ranges correspond to the desired relative sizing.

So for instance, I may want a graph where the first facet occupies 80% and the second 20%. Here is an example:

```
data <- rbind(
    data.frame(x=1:500, y=rnorm(500,sd=1), type='A'), 
    data.frame(x=1:500, y=rnorm(500,sd=5), type='B'))
ggplot() + 
    geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=type), data=data) + 
    facet_grid(type ~ ., scale='free_y')
```

The above creates 2 facets of equal vertical dimension.  Adding in `space='free'` in the `facet_grid` function changes the dimensions such that the lower facet is roughly 5x larger than the upper (as expected).

Supposing I want the upper to be 2x as large, with the same data set and ordering of facets.  How can I accomplish this?

Is the only way to do this with some trickery in rescaling the data set and manually overriding axis labels (and if so, how)?

**Alternative**

As indicated below can use viewports to render as multiple graphs.  I had considered this and in-fact had implemented using this approach in the past with standard plot and viewports.

The problem is that it is very difficult to get x-axis to align with this approach.  So if there is a way to **fix the size** of the y-axis label region and the size of the legend region, can produce 2 graphs that have the same rendering area.

Comment: I should have indicated, but I need the x-axis to align precisely.  Rendering in separate graphs is something considered, but would not work as extremely difficult to get x-axis to align.  This is important as looking at coincident indicators in a timeseries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kohske Takahashi posted a patch to facet_grid that allows specification of the relative sizing of facets.  See the thread:

http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/7c5454dcc04bc7b8

With luck we'll see this in a future version of ggplot2.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use facets for this - you can also do this by using the `viewport` function.

```
> ratio = 1/3
> v1 = viewport(width=1,height=ratio,y=1-ratio/2)
> v2 = viewport(width=1,height=1-ratio,y=(1-ratio)/2)
> print(qplot(1:10,11:20,geom="point"),vp=v1)
> print(qplot(1:10,11:20,geom="line"),vp=v2)
```

Ratio is the proportion of the top panel to the whole page.  Try 2/3 and 4/5 as well.

This approach can get ugly if your legend or axis labels in the two plots are different sizes, but for a fix, see the `align.plots` function in the ggExtra package and ggplot2 author Hadley Wickam's [notes on this very topic](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Align-two-plots-on-a-page).

[image]

---

There's no easy way to do this with facets currently, although if you are prepared to go down to [editing the Grid](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/chapter5.pdf), you can modify the ggplot graph after it has been plotted to get this effect.

---

See also this question on [using grid and ggplot2 to create join plots using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305613/using-grid-and-ggplot2-to-create-join-plots-using-r).

Comment: Those aren't really `facets`, are they?

Comment: You can't do what he wants with facets without going to down to the Grid level.  Also, the secondary data is likely to be using a different dimension from the data, so they may not be appropriate in many cases.

Comment: "Is the only way to do this with some trickery in rescaling the data set and manually overriding axis labels (and if so, how)?" - no, this is not the only way to do this :-)

Comment: Thanks, since Hadley has put something together to align the plots, should work.  I would have preferred a way to do within facets, but is apparent that is not supported.  Thanks for you answer

Comment: I think Hadley is planning a better solution to this whole class of problems.